# Getting a check box from Excel sheet with Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an Excel Sheet with check boxes (Developer -> Controls -> Insert -> Check Box) in cells. I need to check if the check box is ticked or not. If there is a better / easier way to accomplish the same result let me know.
I tried this:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.Visible = $openExcel
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$Table = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheet)
$CheckBox = $Table.Cells.Item($row, $column)
($CheckBox | Format-List | Out-String) | Out-File -File output.txt
```

In the output is no sign of the checkbox in the cell. Do I have to access them differently?

Output: https://pastebin.com/raw/KeAKDi2n

Comment: See the pastebin link

Comment: That's exactly picking the `$Table.Cells.Item`. You were not capturing the checkbox anywhere in your code. Not sure what you were looking for ? Are you trying to insert a check(Tick mark symbol) in a particular cell using powershell? If yes, then approach would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have stated in the comment, for checkbox you need to use something like the below:

```
$CheckBoxes = $ExcelWorkSheet.CheckBoxes()
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(Left,Top,Width,Height)
$checkbox.Value = 1
$checkbox.Text = ""
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see the checkboxes in the output. Is there any way to directly determine in which column & row they are? My only guess would be to all give them a unique name.

Comment: @LouisJ.:  Can you accept my answer if it helps you.? yes you can give the row and cell ID accordingly.